# Should I use the GD library in PHP to draw CAPTCHA images?

Tags: php, security, image, captcha

Is PHP's GD library suitable for drawing images from scratch? Or would I be better off just importing an image and altering it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it'll be possible to know how many people use one solution, or the other ;-)

But the most reasonnable answer would be, in your case, that choosing one solution over the other depends on your situation :

- If you have a base-image and just need to add a small portion of information, loading an existing image will probably be the simplest solution
- If you need to generate an image that's customized a lot, different for each one of your pages, going with a full-generation from scratch might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

No, you defiantly should not write your own captcha.   Please use [re-capthca](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/) it is by far the most secure capthca ever made,  and its free.  If this doesn't work use one of the many [(vulnerable) Capthca libraries](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) that use gdlib.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not limited to GD, you may also want to look at the ImageMagick extension. [This](http://forum.coppermine-gallery.net/index.php?topic=34098.0) has a comparison :)